# How to create a Typescript declaration file for a custom class without require/import/export

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Hoping someone can help get my head around typescript declaration files and how to access my custom-made classes.

So let's imagine I have a custom class to display an alert message as an example:

### CustomAlert.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/CustomAlert.d.ts" />
module MdlCustomAlerts{    
    class CustomAlert{
        constructor(alertMessage:string, alertOptions:IAlertOptions){
            alert(message);
        }
    }
}
```

### CustomAlert.d.ts

```
declare module MdlCustomAlerts{
    interface IAlertOptions{

    }

    class CustomAlert{
      constructor(alertMessage:string, alertOptions:IAlertOptions)
    }
}
```

### app.ts

```
/// <reference path="typings/MyAlert.d.ts" />

var alert1 = new MdlCustomAlerts.CustomAlert("Hello World", {});
```

First of all, I get an 'duplicate identifier' error in CustomAlert.ts as class CustomAlert is defined in the definitions. I need a way of accessing my CustomAlert by using the definitions without the use of import/require (we don't use require.js so this causes issues).

I think I need to do something like export a public identifier for the class (perhaps renaming the class in the definitions to customAlert and then exporting the reference) but I can't seem to make any way work. If someone could help me get to the solution I'd be very grateful!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can reference typescript fies directly from other typescript files; you do not need type definitions for them.

Type definitions are meant to type javascript files for use from Typescript.

... and you should use modules (ES6/commonJS - not what is now called namespaces). Failure to do so, as your application will get bigger, you will fall into nightmarish problems of ordering your TS files to get proper compilation.

**CustomAlert.ts**

```
export class CustomAlert{
  constructor(alertMessage:string, alertOptions:IAlertOptions){
    alert(message);
  }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {CustomAlert} from './CustomAlert'

var alert1 = new CustomAlert("Hello World", {});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I do use modules generally but was intending to try to simplify the problem. I was under the impression that Type definitions were generally a good idea no matter what the source of the code. I thought that it was better to store interfaces externally and to provide a "condensed" version of the library for use in external libraries.

Comment: Using modules also introduces further complexity that ideally I would like to solve. For example, I would ideally like (using the example above) new CustomAlert("Message", {}) to be available directly rather than having to reach it using new MdlCustomAlertModule.CustomAlert("Message",{}); I thought a definition would make this possible...?

Comment: If you are building a library, then yes generating the definition files makes ense because you will be shipping js + the definition files so your library can be used from JS and TS

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments - but using a definition file also allows you to comment the code and provide more information for the library - rather than having to do this directly in the typescript source. And provides a nicer place to reference other libraries that are being used.

Comment: This is in regards to building a library (currently we have approx 30 different libraries which often interact with each other). Ideally I would like to be moving these onto a private NuGet server as well. So I'm hoping there is still an answer to my question somewhere out there!

Comment: I believe your are mixing Modules and Namespaces. I am talking about using ES6/commonJS style modules. Namespaces on the other hand are usually not neded or even a bad idea

Comment: I get errors using the import command as we are not using require.js (i thought that these were linked but please tell me if i'm incorrect)

Comment: You need to compile to target ES6 or commonJS. Babel is you friend if you want to compile ES6 down to ES5, webpack is your other friend to go from commonJS to ES5

Comment: Thanks Bruno - I am now compiling to target commonJS. I am working in a large and established C#/.Net framework so adding new tools is a lengthy - rather than ad-hoc - process Referencing the .ts file and using import {CustomAlert} from './MdlCustomAlerts'; I get the error 'Cannot find module './MdlCustomAlerts'

Comment: is `MdlCustomAlerts.ts` in the same directory as the importing files ?  This should work straight out of the box

Comment: No it's in a different directory. I'm first referencing the .ts file - and then trying to import. The import needs to point to the right directory? Like import {CustomAlert} from '../../../anotherDir/CustomAlerts.ts' ?

Comment: yes it must be pointing to the relative path containing the file